# What does this elastisearch query do?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm executing the following query and I was expecting it to fetch me all the documents that contain the keyword "images" and are under categories 1857 or 1859. However the number of results is significantly higher than the one expected. What does this query do if not what I thought it does?

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "category_id": [1857, 1859]
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "_all": {
          "query": "images"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of documents that shouldn't match but appear as search results?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have full access to the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as you described: it returns documents where `category_id` has terms 1857 or 1859 and at least one field has `images` term. In other words, it's matches the following expression: `(category_id in (1857, 1859)) and _all = 'images'`.

Since you can't provide an example  of incorrectly matched documents, try to run your query with `explain` querystring parameter or add it as a field to the body like this

```
{
    "explain": true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "category_id": [
                            1857,
                            1859
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "_all": {
                            "query": "images"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, what does this query do? Does it fetch all the documents where "image" appears in any term *and* 1857 appears in category_id *or* 1859 does?

Comment: Updated my answer